# restricting Doctrine annotated joins

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I have a class `Folder` with these fields:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var Folder
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FileBundle\Entity\Folder", inversedBy="subFolders", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_folder_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
private $parentFolder;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FileBundle\Entity\Folder", mappedBy="parentFolder")
 * @ORM\OrderBy("name")
 */
private $subFolders;
```

I have a function in my Repository that selects folders where the user is the current user or Null.
I would like to have the same rules for my subfolders. I tried this, which didn't work, obviously.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('folder');
$qb
    ->leftJoin(
        'folder.subFolders',
        'folders',
        'with',
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->isNull('folders.user'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('folders.user', ':user')
        )
    )
    ->add('where', $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->isNull('folder.parentFolder'),
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->isNull('folder.user'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('folder.user', ':user')
        )
    ))
    ->orderBy('folder.name')
    ->setParameter('user', $user->getId());

return $qb;
```

Well, the query works, but this doesn't affect my subfolders, because I still get subfolders created by another user.

If you could nudge me in the correct direction, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In leftJoin method you have to specify the entity as a first parameter. You are joining the same table, so you have to join Folder::class, not folder.subFolders. Hopefully, helpfull :)

Comment: thanks @Vladislav, but actually the join works, since I've been able to test this by just doing the SQL. The answer by tmas is exactly what I needed. Thanks for trying though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add ->addSelect('folders') to the query
If you don't do the addSelect the relation won't be initialized in your entity. So if you later on do `getSubFolders()` the relation won't be initialized and it will just do a regular select without your requirements from the join.
With the addSelect all the folders will be eager loaded with your requirements.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('folder');
$qb
    ->addSelect('folders')
    ->leftJoin(
        'folder.subFolders',
        'folders',
        'with',
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->isNull('folders.user'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('folders.user', ':user')
        )
    )
    ->add('where', $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->isNull('folder.parentFolder'),
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->isNull('folder.user'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('folder.user', ':user')
        )
    ))
    ->orderBy('folder.name')
    ->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
```